# Adding hfsplus file system to fstab

Tags: raspbian, filesystem, mount, fstab

I have a external drive that is formatted in HFSX. And I have installed the hfsplus etc using

```
sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs
```

After this I have retrieved the UUID for the disk using `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` (lets say it was 12345)

And then created a folder `/mount/USBDrive/` and tried to mount the device into this folder using

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw UUID=12345 /media/UDBDrive/
```

This seem to work super and I see all my files etc. Now I would like to add this into my `fstab` and this is when the problem starts...

So in my `/etc/fstab` file I add the row

```
UUID=12345 /media/USBDrive/ hfsplus force,rw,default 0 0
```

(I'm not sure about the `force,rw` but I have tried without it and it makes no differens)

Anyway, after adding this to my `fstab` I run `sudo mount /media/USBDrive/` and I get the following error message:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

and the `dmesg` reports:

```
hfsplus: unable to parse mount options
```

Soo...  Why can I mount it using the "manual" mount command, but not using the `fstab`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the options that you used on the command line:

```
UUID=12345 /media/USBDrive/ hfsplus force,rw
```

The `0 0` part at the end is optional. You tried with the extra option `default` which is not a valid option name (there's a [`defaults`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191405/do-you-need-to-specify-the-defaults-option-in-fstab), but it isn't useful here).